# Retraction of $\{(z_1, ..., z_n) \in \Bbb C^n : \sum z_k^2 \neq 0 \} $ onto $\{(z_1, ..., z_n) \in \Bbb C^n : \sum z_k^2=1 \}$

Tags: general-topology

Consider the space $X:=\{(z_1, ..., z_n) \in \Bbb C^n : \sum z_k^2 \neq 0 \} $ and its closed subspace $Y:=\{(z_1, ..., z_n) \in X : \sum z_k^2=1 \}$. Is there a retraction of $X$ onto $Y$? Or, more generally, is there a continuous surjection $X \to Y$? Intuitively it seems true, but I got stuck constructing such a map. Any helps will be appreciated. (Both $X$ and $Y$ have the Euclidean topology.)

Comment: Won't $ z \mapsto z/||z|| $ work?

Comment: @P-addict It doesn't. It is not well defined, for example in $ \Bbb C^2$, consider the image of $( \sqrt{2}, i)$

Comment: correct, its not $\mathbb{R^{n}}$.

Comment: $f(z) = \sum_j z_j^2$ then image by $f$ of the intermediate sets must be contained in $f(X) = \Bbb{C}^*$ which is not simply connected so it cannot retract to a point

Comment: @reuns What are the "intermediate sets"? And $\mathbb C^*$ retracts to a point (although it doesn't deformation retract).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No for $n=1$. We have $X = \{ z \in \mathbb C \mid z^2 \ne 0\} =\{ z \in \mathbb C \mid z \ne 0\} = \mathbb C \setminus  \{ 0 \}$ and $Y = \{ z \in X \mid z^2 =1 \} = \{-1,1\}$. Since $X$ is connected whereas $Y$ is not, there does not exist a continuous surjecton $X \to Y$.